# How to find folder in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a project with a lot of files and folders. There are no problems with finding files. They can be found with Ctrl-P. But there are many folders in which files with the same name are made. Therefore, it is easier to search for a file by the name of the folder in which it is located. How in VS Code to search for folders in the current open project?

For example, I have the following project structure:

```
A/
    main.js
B/
    main.js
...
Z/
    main.js
```

The file `main.js` from the folder `P` will be easier to find by the folder name.

Comment: Open issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30404 - they suggest typing "P main"

Comment: If what you want is filter folders in the project explorer, that's not possible. Using ctrl+P (or cmd+P) is however an easy way to do this. Simply put `/myfolder` or `folder/file` or even `folder/*/file`. You'll see files contained by that folder and the full path so.. like finding the folder.

Comment: Wish they had something like IntelliJ does. Add a trailing slash and it searches for folders (when searching for files in the popup).

Comment: @pank i came here looking for the same. Seems like the feature-request has mutated : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/27317... You can use P or use the incorporated terminal in the meantime.

Answer (score 27):

While using <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd>, you can type the full path of the file, so if i have two files named bar you can search on <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> with
"foo/bar" or with "qux/bar"
Vscode uses fuzzy search (like so many others), so you don't have to actually type the whole thing.
There is no way, to my knowledge and research, to find and be directed to a specific directory.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply select a folder on the explorer and tape some filter keywords.

Recently, vscode added a shortcut, if you are using a recent release just typing won't work, first tape `ctrl + f`.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This VSCode extension does exactly what you're asking for.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rwu823.open-folder

Comment: This seems to open all the files in a matched folder. I'd prefer just to display it in the Explorer view

Answer (score 6):

> Ctrl + Shift + E

and start typing. You'll see your search on the top right corner of file explorer.

By default it does not filter by result but your focus will jumps to the  first one. From there you can Enter to open it.

If you want to show only results containing the string of search : click on filter icon next to your search (state will be remembered).

> Echap

to exit/remove search
or

> Ctrl + Shift + E

again to switch back focus to last place you were typing.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to search through subfolders. Click on a folder you wish to search, than <kbd>/</kbd> and start typing for a name of subfolder

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Just open the parent folder of your folder in VSCode. Then right-click on the folder you want to find subfolder in and choose "Find in folder"

Answer (score 0):

Click on any file/folder in the explorer. Then press Ctrl + F.
A search bar will come up in the explorer and you can search for the file you want.